# Could not load System.Core 4.0 in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: .net, dll, windows-10, portable-class-library, windows-10-universal

I am having an issue with the latest version of Window 10 Universal App and PCL libraries

This DLL must be on the system because a previous version of a UWP10 worked with the same library. I have tried to download .NET Framework 4 KB fixes but they won't be installed on Windows 10 stating :

- Another Version of this product already exist
- OR Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system. Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer.

  {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}

Comment: I work on the .NET Native Runtime and Compiler team. UWP applications are not building or running against the .NET framework that comes with Windows so it's unlikely that any changes there will help out. If you're still experiencing this issue I'd love to look at it with you. can you send a mail to dotnetnative@micrsoft.com?

Comment: I am facing this issue as well, using VS2015 and Windows 10 the app is building and at runtime facing this System.Core exception along with 'mscorlib' dll exception as well any help.? @linvi have you been able to resolve this.?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I've ever had same problem with you.

When you make an app with selecting Blank app (Universal Windows), the app has reference System.Core like below image.

[image]

But, when you make an app with selecting Blank app (Xamarin.Forms Portable), there is no System.Core.

[image]

**As a result, you could not use the .dll you use with uwp10.
But if you want to use the .dll, you need to port through PCL API to get rid of using System.Core API.**